# Extract SMTP address from Outlook in VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, outlook, smtp

I have an Access script which successfully sends emails bypassing Outlook using smtp credentials.

However I want my script to automatically detect the smtp server per user that uses this rather than having to hardcode it into the script or type it manually.  Can anyone help with this?

Edit:

This is the current code I'm using.  I don't want to use any 3rd Party tools in order to acheive this.

```
Public Sub send_email()


Dim iCfg As Object
Dim iMsg As Object
Dim dtm As Date
Dim dtt As Date

dtm = DateValue(Now)
dtt = TimeValue(Now)

Set iCfg = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
'SMTP Server settings with username and password fields
With iCfg.Fields
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "NHS-PCLI-     MBC013.AD1.NET"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") =    LabelFrom.Caption
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = LabelPass.Caption
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendemailaddress") = LabelFrom.Caption
.Update
End With

'Form the email with user input settings and date with time as set by system
With iMsg
.Configuration = iCfg
.From = LabelFrom.Caption
.Subject = LabelSubject.Caption & " <DB Form Sent " & dtm & " " & dtt & ">"
.To = LabelTo.Caption
.TextBody = LabelBody.Caption
.Send
MsgBox ("Email sent")
fldBody.Value = ""
Password.Value = ""
fldTo.Value = ""
fldFrom.Value = ""
fldSubject.Value = ""
LabelBody.Caption = ""
LabelTo.Caption = ""
LabelFrom.Caption = ""
LabelSubject.Caption = ""
LabelPass.Caption = ""
End With

Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iCfg = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: Can we see your existing code and get a little more info?  Just guessing, but think this will be tricky.  If you are having the user provide the "From" address, then you'd have to do a Mxlookup to verify the SMTP, and also have them provide the credentials to that server.